# Trouble passing MongoDB document to HTML (Flask & Pymongo)

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-pymongo

I am having trouble passing a document from my MongoDB database to an HTML file I have rendered using flask. My database is called **users** and has fields "_id", "name", "username", and "score" in it. I want to set up an HTML page for the profile of a user who is currently logged into the session. so I wrote it like this in my flask app.py:

```
@app.route("/profile", methods=["GET","POST"])
def profile():
   user = mongo.db.users.find({'username': session['username']})
   return render_template("profile.html", user=user)
```

Here I am trying to find the document in the database where the username is equal to the current username in the session, and then I pass that to my HTML page. Then in my HTML page I have this:

```
<body>
    <h1>Your Profile</h1>
    <p>{{ user['name'] }}</p>
    <p>{{ user['score'] }}</p>
            
</body>
```

But when I look at this on my local server while logged in, nothing shows up. Is my syntax correct? Can anyone tell me what I have wrong?

Comment: Any errors? find() returns a cursor; you might want to use find_one() instead which returns a dict.